# WPF задать триггер стиля для всех ячеек

Tags: wpf, datagrid, style

в гриде несколько столбцов. нужно чтобы font color ячейки был серым если значение=0. можно указать стиль для каждого столбца, но получается громоздко. нельзя ли задать стиль для самой таблицы? то же самое хотел бы и для HeaderStyle

```
<DataGrid>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt1}" 
            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
            Header="0-1" 
            Width="100">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                    Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <!-- еще несколько таких же -->


    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Что бы не было громоздко - вынесите стиль в ресурс и используйте его в виде статичного ресурса.

Comment: Либо написать наследника `DataGridTextColumn` и переопределить стили для ячеек в нем, если колонок много и вы не хотите для каждой писать `ElementStyle="{StaticResource MyElementStyle}" ...`. Пример здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882985/218063